# @disallowconcurrentexecution will really work?

Tags: java, concurrency, quartz

I have used @disallowconcurrentexecution in my job to avoid the concurrent execution and I have used the SAME job instances (Job detail with same name) for every trigger. Still its not working.

The code is executing concurrently, line by line.

I have been checking this for past 3 days. No hope. Is there anybody in the world who got this @disallowconcurrentexecution executed properly. Please let me know. I really wanna know what did I wrong.

Comment: Post related code, please.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question. Without it, it is nearly impossible to know *exactly* where the issue lies.